# how to add <script>alert('test');</script> inside a text box?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is strange requirement!

I want to `<script>alert('test');</script>` in an input type text but it should not execute the `alert()`.

I just need to set the text `<script>alert('test');</script>`.
Am using **nwt framework**... And also is this do-able in JS?

Thanks,
Md Waseem

Comment: Define "text box". Do you mean an `<input type="text">`? How do you usually set the value of one of those? What problem are you having with the value you want to set?

Comment: yes quentin! its input type="text". I usually do it element.value="<script>alert('test');</script>". So bsically i have an XSS issue where in when a user enters <script>alert('test');</script> . For this am doing escape and doing an unescape to set in input type="text" but that seems to be executing the alert

Comment: please post your HTML/JS to here, it is hard to understand what is your problem

Comment: *"So bsically i have an XSS issue where in when a user enters `<script>alert('test');</script>`"* If the code the user enters is only executed in their browser, don't worry, that's not an XSS issue. A user can just open the console and execute any code they want. *"For this am doing escape and doing an unescape [...] but that seems to be executing the alert"* It seems you are evaluating the code which you should not do. Since you didn't post your code, we cannot help you in that regard though.

Comment: @FelixKling — Not so. A user could visit a (malicious) third party site that causes the browser to submit a form to the vulnerable site.

Comment: @Quentin: True... let me rephrase that. I removed that part and stressed what I actually wanted to say.

Comment: do you want fix XSS issue on input field?

Answer (score 4):

> . I usually do it `element.value="<script>alert('test');</script>"`.

If sounds like you are generating an inline `<script>` element, in which case the `</script>` will end the HTML element and cause the script to terminate in the middle of the string.

Escape the `/` so that it isn't treated as an end tag by the HTML parser:

```
element.value = "<script>alert('test');<\/script>"
```

Comment: `searchfieldvalue="<script>alert('test');</script>";    searchtextfilter._node.value=searchfieldvalue.replace(/<\/script>/,'<\/script>');`

Quetine is this correct ?

Comment: No. You need `'<\\/script>'` (and this assumes you are generating client side code as described in the answer, if you aren't and all the JS is running server side, then this can't be the problem … and you need to look at the generated HTML source code and then ask a question about either what HTML you need (showing the HTML you have now and not involving the server side JS) or how to generate the HTML that you want (showing the HTML you have, the HTML you want and enough of the server side JS to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Am doing this in the client side so while setting inside the input text i should do this `searchtextfilter._node.value=searchfieldvalue.replace(/<\/script>/,'<\\/script‌​>');` ?? Please check with this regex

Comment: If you're doing this client side, and the problem is as described in this answer, then that won't work because the script element will already have been parsed and it will be too late to change it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok to answer this . I simply converted my `<` and the `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. What was happening previously is i used to set the text `<script>alert('1')</script>` but before setting the text in the input text browserconverts `&lt;` and `&gt;` as `<` and the `>`. So hence converting them again to `&lt;` and `&gt;`since browser will understand that as only tags and converts them , than executing the script inside `<input type="text" />`

Answer (score -2):

> I want to alert('test'); in an input type text but it should not execute the alert(alert prompt).

```
<input type="text" value="<script>alert('test');</script>" />
```

Produces:

[image]

You can do this programatically via JavaScript. First obtain a reference to the input element, then set the `value` attribute.

```
var inputElement = document.querySelector("input");
inputElement.value = "<script>alert('test');<\/script>";
```

Comment: searchfieldvalue="<script>alert('test');<\/script>";
      searchtextfilter._node.value=searchfieldvalue.replace(/<\/script>/,'<\/script>');

IS this correct ?

Answer (score -2):

is you want fix XSS on input element?
you can encode string before output to input field

PHP:

```
$str = htmlentities($str);
```

C#:

```
str = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(str);
```

after that output value direct to input field:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $str" />
```

Comment: Thnx! but i need to this JS.

Answer (score -4):

JQuery version:

```
$('yourInputSelectorHere').val("<script>alert('test');<\/script>")
```

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"A pure JavaScript answer is usually expected, except if a tag for a framework or library is also present."*. There are certainly situations where suggesting to use jQuery is acceptable, but jQuery really isn't needed here.